# Entity Framework to Query Xml

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-4, sqlxml

I have an issue. Perhaps one of you experts can help out here. The table that I am querying has 2 xml columns. I need to perform query on xml data in these columns too ( in my advanced search functionality ). Problem is I am using Entity Framework and it doesnt support that. Even if I try to do "ObjectQuery.Execute" it causes Syntax Error. So what are my options here ?

1. Modify the table and add columns for the data that is in XML which I need to query, so that I can use Entity Framework to perform the operation ?
2. Just for Advanced Search use ODBC and do regular query where I would be able to use SQLXml ? What are the potential threats here [ like multiple connection, too many connections, Abomination of design/Architect etc ] ?
3. Or can anyone propose a better solution to this ?

Thanks,

Ali Nahid

Comment: Please add some more details on the exception. As stated in my answer, it's possible to work with XML using EF.

Comment: I want to do something like this:
<pre>
<code>SELECT it.Id, it.Name, it.SomeData, it2.someotherdata FROM Table1 as it 
CROSS APPLY it.XmlData.nodes('/FORM/PAGES/PAGE/FIELDS/FIELD[@name="LOCATION"]') location(tRef), Table2 as it2
WHERE it.Id = it2.Table2RefId AND
it.Live = 1 AND location.tRef.value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') LIKE '%Venn%'
ORDER BY id DESC </code>
</pre>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EF maps SQL Server XML type columns to strings. So for this definition:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[XmlData](
[ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[XmlTestColumn] [xml] NOT NULL
)
```

you would have the following entity:

```
public partial class XmlData
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string XmlTestColumn { get; set; }
}
```

and would be able load the string into XmlDocument, etc. That's one approach.

If you prefer to issue a native XML query against SQL Server, you'll need to

1. Define or choose a suitable entity type;
2. Use `Database.SqlQuery` with a your XML query:

   var query = context.Database.SqlQuery(@"SELECT it.Id, it.Name, it.SomeData, t2.someotherdata FROM Table1 as it CROSS APPLY ...");

`ObjectQuery` works against the conceptual model and does not support native queries.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But this is not my problem. This way I need to query in the DB first without querying XMLData in the XML column of the table. Then I will have to iterate the resultset and query the XML data.
But there is an another functionality in the SQL Server from SQL Server 2005.. that you can do XMLSQL query. See my comments to your ans in the above post. 
Thanks.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Makes sense. But I can't confirm if it works now because I am running .NET4 hence I dont have the Database.SqlQuery in my System.Data.Entity lib. For that I will have to install 4.5 which overwrites 4.0. But I can't do that unless I test that nothing on my current application breaks as well as on the server (as there're multiple apps on IIS + Umbraco [this is where I'm being scared]). Regrettably it probably sounds like a risky update.